# submit function not executing in angularjs even it meet the requirments

Tags: angularjs, service, controller, factory

I have form, when a user enter data into it and submit the data, the data should go to controller and convert the string into JSON object, then got to submit function and check the condition. If condition is true, it should go to factory service and create a new user and display the details in console.  
If the condition is false a message should display in console as "user already exist".  The issue is it is going to controller page but submit function is not executing 
**The HTML code**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">

    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="createfranctrl as ctrl">

        <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()"  name="myForm" action="" method="post" class="form-horizontal center-block"  id="create-franchise-form" >
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Create Franchise</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-name">Franchise Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                  <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.franame" class="form-control" name="franchisor-name" id="franchisor-name" placeholder="Franchisor Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-city">City:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.city" class="form-control" name="franchisor-city" id="franchisor-city" placeholder="City" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchise-name">Name:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.name" class="form-control" name="franchise-name" id="franchise-name" placeholder="Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-user-id">User ID:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.user.uid" class="form-control" name="franchisor-user-id" id="franchisor-user-id" placeholder="User ID" required>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-password">Password:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                  <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password" class="form-control" name="franchisor-password" id="franchisor-password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,}$" title="password must 1 Capital Letter, 1 Small Letter, 1 Number and min 6 Letters ">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-mobile">Mobile:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.mobile" class="form-control" name="franchisor-mobile" id="franchisor-mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" title="Mobile should contain 10 numbers start with 7,8,9" maxlength="10">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-email">E-Mail:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">          
                <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" class="form-control" name="franchisor-email" id="franchisor-email" placeholder="E-Mail" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">        
              <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">CREATE</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">CLEAR</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>    
        </form>
    </div></body>
```

**controller code**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').controller('createfranctrl', ['$scope', 'createservice', function($scope, createservice) {
var self = this;
   self.user={franame:'',city:'',name:'',uid:null,password:'',mobile:'',email:''};
self.user=[];

self.submit = submit;
console.log("loading ctrl file");

function submit() {
    console.log('enter submit function');
    if(self.user.uid===null){
        console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
        createUser(self.user);
    }else{
        console.log('user already exist');
    }
}

   function createUser(user){
    console.log("enter create function");
    createservice.createUser(user);
        }
}]);
```

**factory code**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('createservice', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

var factory = {
    fetchAllUsers: fetchAllUsers,
    createUser: createUser
};

return factory;

function fetchAllUsers() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(data)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.log('Error while fetching Users');
            deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

function createUser(user) {
    console.log('create in service');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(data, user)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while creating User');
            deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

}]);
```

Comment: Why do you declare self.user as an array(self.user=[];) after you've already initialized it as an object?  The way you are using it in your form indicates that it should be an object not an array.

Comment: Side note: You can change your factory functions to `return $http.get(..)` and `return $http.post(..)` instead of using the `deferred` anti pattern, thus saving yourself about 20 lines of redundant code.

Comment: jbrown thanks for looking into that, I have change it but still it's not working, I have updated about the issue can you have a look at that

Comment: remove `action=""` attribute from form and add `novalidate` to disable auto-check from html

Answer (score 0):

The way you've declared your module is incorrect.

Here is a working [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/i9euQns5ffrGThDJjLpG?p=info).

```
angular.module('myApp')
```

should be

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
```

Comment: check your plunker it's not opening

Comment: @prasad - fixed the plunker link

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. Removed attribute `action=""` to prevent page refresh and added `novalidate` to disable HTML checks.

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="createfranctrl as ctrl">
        <form ng-submit="ctrl.submit()"  name="myForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal center-block"  id="create-franchise-form" novalidate>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Create Franchise</legend>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-name">Franchise Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.franame" class="form-control" name="franchisor-name" id="franchisor-name" placeholder="Franchisor Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-city">City:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.city" class="form-control" name="franchisor-city" id="franchisor-city" placeholder="City" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchise-name">Name:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.name" class="form-control" name="franchise-name" id="franchise-name" placeholder="Name" required pattern="[A-Za-z]{4,}">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-user-id">User ID:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.user.uid" class="form-control" name="franchisor-user-id" id="franchisor-user-id" placeholder="User ID" required>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-password">Password:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="password" ng-model="ctrl.user.password" class="form-control" name="franchisor-password" id="franchisor-password" placeholder="Password" required pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{6,}$" title="password must 1 Capital Letter, 1 Small Letter, 1 Number and min 6 Letters ">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-mobile">Mobile:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.user.mobile" class="form-control" name="franchisor-mobile" id="franchisor-mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required pattern="[789][0-9]{9}" title="Mobile should contain 10 numbers start with 7,8,9" maxlength="10">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="franchisor-email">E-Mail:</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">          
                        <input type="email" ng-model="ctrl.user.email" class="form-control" name="franchisor-email" id="franchisor-email" placeholder="E-Mail" required pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">        
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-success">CREATE</button>
                        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger">CLEAR</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

**main.js** - When the first time we define the module the `angular.module` function requires 2 parameters. Read more here: [AngularJS.module API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp', []).controller('createfranctrl', ['$scope', 'createservice', function($scope, createservice) {
    var self = this;
    self.user={franame:'',city:'',name:'', uid:null, password:'', mobile:'', email:''};
    self.user=[];

    self.submit = submit;
    console.log("loading ctrl file");

    function submit() {
        console.log('enter submit function');
        if(!self.user.uid){
            console.log('Saving New User', self.user);
            createUser(self.user);
        }else{
            console.log('user already exist');
        }
    }

    function createUser(user){
        console.log("enter create function");
        createservice.createUser(user);
    }
}]);
```

**createservice.js** - Factory file will work with just 1 parameter in `angular.module` as we are only retrieving previously created module.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp').factory('createservice', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q){

var factory = {
    fetchAllUsers: fetchAllUsers,
    createUser: createUser
};

return factory;

function fetchAllUsers() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(data)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.log('Error while fetching Users');
            deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

function createUser(user) {
    console.log('create in service');
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.post(data, user)
        .then(
        function (response) {
            deferred.resolve(response.data);
        },
        function(errResponse){
            console.error('Error while creating User');
            deferred.reject(errResponse);
        }
    );
    return deferred.promise;
}

}]);
```